# Android Studio Errors | :app:checkDebugAarMetadata

Tags: android, gradle

Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
> Could not find android.cardview: cardview:1.0.0.
> Searched in the following locations:
> - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/android/cardview/ cardview/1.0.0/ cardview-1.0.0.pom
> - https://jcenter.bintray.com/android/cardview/ cardview/1.0.0/ cardview-1.0.0.pom
> Required by:
> project :app

Possible solution:

- Declare repository providing the artifact, see the documentation at https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html

Comment: post your app.gradle files there is cardview dependcy is missing I guess

Comment: Please include the gradle files

Answer (score 1):

try adding the cardview dependency in your build.gradle(App Level)

Gradle Groovy DSL:

```
implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
```

Gradle Kotlin DSL:

```
implementation("androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0")
```

Explanation for beginners from @JustInCoding: The library cardview is found within AndroidX, and not just Android.

Comment: Explanation: The library cardview is found within AndroidX, and not just Android.

@Beast, add this to your answer for beginners